# ASP.Net Core - Call a static method from Razor View - Build Fail without giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to call a static method from my razor view.

I have tried these 2 function (for the same purpose)-

**1. Extension Function**

```
public static String GetPresentableClaimName(this String text)
{
    string[] textArr = text.Split(".");
    Array.Reverse(textArr);
    return string.Join(" ", textArr);
}
```

**2. Normal Function**

```
public static String GetPresentableClaimNameFromString(String text)
{
    string[] textArr = text.Split(".");
    Array.Reverse(textArr);
    return string.Join(" ", textArr);
}
```

Then in razor view, I am importing like this for the first function-

```
@item.ClaimValue.GetPresentableClaimName()
```

And for the second function, I am doing this-

```
@Utility.GetPresentableClaimNameFromString(@item.ClaimValue)
```

Where `item` is my model object and `ClaimValue` is a string property in that object.

For both of the cases, I am finding this-

[image: error building project]

When I am trying to build or rebuild the project. but no error is showing.

Can anyone please help me to find what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your `Utility` class (or the class in which your extension method is) is not public.

Comment: My utility is defined as this- `public static class Utility`, so everything is public.

Comment: And that long line (3rd from below) doesn't contain any description of error?

Comment: That is the most astonishing things I currently have :(

Comment: I have used the internal keyword in some other places which are used in the pipeline. Can that be the issue?

Comment: Yes it should be public to use from razor page, even if it's in the same project.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. Thank you @Evk

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with help of @Evk by changing the class from `internal` to `public`